# how to find funcation name based on address in library

Tags: c

I'm printing stacks from my c code using backtrace_symbols() (following instructions on http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html). However, I can only get the addresses of the stack frames in the dynamic library even though I built the library using -g -rdynamic .

Now, I have the running process and I have the library, how do I find out which method each frame address corresponds to?  Thank you in advance.

This is on 64bit Linux.

The example of my print out looks like this:

```
Obtained 9 stack frames.
/tmp/libexample.so [0x2aaabaae9771]
/tmp/libexample.so [0x2aaabaae9828]
/tmp/libexample.so [0x2aaabaaa8138]
/tmp/libexample.so [0x2aaabaab2402]
/tmp/libexample.so [0x2aaabaabd029]
/tmp/libexample.so [0x2aaabaa1e23a]
/tmp/libexample.so [0x2aaabaa24ded]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x30b700677d]
```

Comment: Are you compiling with debugging symbols enabled? `-g` with GCC and Clang

Comment: Yes. With -g. Just added that via edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `dladdr` function.

Comment: I looked at the man page of dladdr. Looks like you can get an address of a function. In my case, I need to go the other way around. Is there a command line tool? I still have the process running that has the library loaded.